# $(...).bootstrapTable is not a function even if it is declared before the end of the body

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

Need help in solving this. I'm encountering the error `$(...).bootstrapTable is not a function` even if I have declared it in the page. Below is the screenshot of the page.
[image]

I hope you can help me with this.

**UPDATE**

This does not happen in version 1.11. It only happens in version 1.12. What I did was to replace the one I used from the previous project and I didn't encounter this. I'm not sure if version 1.12 is stable or not.

Comment: did you check required .js files are loaded under  'Sources'

Comment: What do you mean under "Sources"?

Comment: It will be next to Console  in Chrome browser.

Comment: Yup. It is also declared there same as in the picture.

Comment: Please post the url. So we can test it in different ways.

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot because it is still under development

Comment: Please check the line number of error. I think you might have used bootstrapTable function before loading the file.

Comment: It points to this line of code `$("#UserTable").bootstrapTable("destroy");`

Comment: Can you just post the source code in  a fiddle.

Comment: Please see my update. I'm not sure if you encountered this or not

Answer (score 0):

Try changing position of bootstrap-table.js in view. You may be getting the error because of script conflict

Comment: How can there be a conflict when there is no declaration of another bootstrap-table.js in the page except for this?